# Installing xubuntu over ubuntu (dual boot with windows)

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation

I currently have Ubuntu 13.10 installed dual-boot with Windows 7. I want to install Xubuntu 13.10 over Ubuntu 13.10 without messing up with Windows and without losing my data in Ubuntu so: is there a way to install Xubuntu over ubuntu and keep all my data and all my programs? or do I have to uninstall ubuntu ( and lose all my data) and then install xubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

You just have to install the xfce desktop:

```
sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop
```

If after installing xfce you want to uninstall Unity, you need to follow the specific instructions for your ubuntu version.

http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/purexubuntu

Comment: +1, good answer, note that psychocats has not updated her instructions since 12.10 on the link you provided, her new updates were moved to her [blog](http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntucat/tag/pure-xubuntu/)

Comment: Note that anyone who reads the whole article can see the newer tutorials were moved.

Comment: yes I saw that, I was just commenting in case someone missed the link, it is not very large compared to the information on the rest of the page.  Better to add clarification that is not needed than to have someone use the wrong info and frag their system...